# Safety of Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, security

I have a laptop that has both windows 7 and Ubuntu with a shared drive (so I a can share files between the operating systems).

I use Windows 7 when I want to use a special program.  I like to keep Ubuntu light and I only use it for surfing the internet and logging into my accounts.

If I download a shady program on Windows 7, can it infect the Ubuntu partition?

Answer (score 5):

In general, malware targeted on Windows systems can't infect systems of such a different type as Linux is. Other than that, Windows is not capable of accessing or even detecting `ext4` (and similar) file systems, which are used by Ubuntu, without having special drivers installed,  so to Windows, your Ubuntu partition looks unused/unformatted.

Although this might read as if your dual-boot Ubuntu installation was 100% safe from harm through Windows or Windows applications (including malware), but this is unfortunately not the case.

We said that Windows can't access the Ubuntu partition's file system, but it can very well access the raw partition (and format it itself or overwrite it otherwise) or the partition table (and delete or move/resize the partition, which destroys it as well). And whatever Windows can do, a good enough malware program can do too.

Also I claimed that Windows applications are not runnable on Ubuntu, so that if such a malware managed to get on your file system, you could not accidentally run it with Ubuntu. This is true for compiled binaries ("exe"/PE files on Windows - in contrast to mainly ELF files on Linux, but no filename extension needed), which are usually platform-dependent. There are however also cross-platform executables and especially scripts (Python, Java, ...) which may be run or interpreted on both system types. Same with malware embedded into documents like PDF files.

So to conclude: There's no 100% safety. I would guess that 99% of all Viruses you can get on your Windows system are not able to do harm to your Ubuntu installation, but there's still 1% left. Make regular backups and nothing should be able to worry you.

Comment: If you are using Windows 7 or newer, the shady program will need Administrator privileges for this.

Comment: @StigHemmer ...which is not impossible or difficult, if `malware programmer's skills >> user's caution`.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule: yes, it could.

This is because, by definition, when you download a piece of "malware", you don't really know what is it that it's doing. It will have (low-level) access to the disk, so it could do things to your linux installation, even if it is not mounted, and it uses a different filesystem.

If your linux installation has full volume encryption, then it may be safer because everything is encrypted. The malware could however damage it. Also, it could plug itself into the boot directory (which is unencrypted) and then wait until you start Ubuntu.

All of this is highly unlikely, because it would require a malware that specifically targets Ubuntu. However...who may know??

Comment: If you are using Windows 7 or newer, the malware will need Administrator privileges for this.

Answer (score 0):

For starters : Windows can't even mount an ext file system by default in the first place, so the chances of Windows accessing your Ubuntu partition is very unlikely and a Windows virus that infects a Linux machine on another drive or partition is still very unlikely.

Windows viruses have no affect on a Linux Operating system, so there is no need to worry.

In my opinion

- Windows viruses run on Windows and can't infect any thing else other
  than Windows.
- Linux viruses run on Linux and can't infect any thing else other than
  Linux.